# Recursion leads to list IndexError

Tags: python, list, recursion, index-error

I'm trying to:

1 - Generate a list of numbers (specifically RGB colors);

2 - Get a random number from said list;

3 - Select the numbers of that list that are sufficiently distant from this random number;

4 - Get a new random number from this new list.

Rinse and repeat k - 1 times.

This is a MWE:

```py
import math
import random
import seaborn as sns

num_list = list(sns.color_palette('rainbow', 10))

base_num = random.choice(num_list)


def distant_numbers(base_num, num_list, dist):
    
    selectables = []

    for num in num_list:
        if math.dist(base_num, num) >= dist:
            selectables.append(num)
    
    new_base_num = random.choice(selectables)
    
    return distant_numbers(new_base_num, selectables, dist)
```

But

```py
for k in range(3):
    print(distant_numbers(base_num, num_list, 0.1))
```

Gives `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Comment: In your own words, what do you think would happen, when `new_base_num = random.choice(selectables)` runs, if `selectables` is an empty list? Can that happen? (Hint: what would happen if the `if math.dist(base_num, num) >= dist:` condition doesn't get met, for any of the `num`s `in num_list`?) Also, please show [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) errors when looking for help with an error, and please only post [after making your own best attempt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: "This is a MWE:" No, this isn't even close to minimum. Right off the top, it should be obvious that using `seaborn` to get some initial random data shouldn't be necessary to reproduce the problem. Also, for *reproducible* behavior, consider making the example show a random number seed known to result in the error. But really, the main thing missing here is the debugging attempt.

Comment: I don't see how this code raises IndexError at all, because there is no list index access anywhere...

Comment: Also, `distant_numbers()` ALWAYS calls itself at the end, which will lead to infinite recursion.  This can't be your real code.

Comment: @JohnGordon it isn't required to be "real code" on Stack Overflow (and in fact usually shouldn't be), but it is required to be an example that others can **copy and paste, without changing or adding anything** to see the **exact** reported problem **directly**. But yes, `random.choice` from an empty sequence does give an `IndexError`, although on my version the message is different.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel _random.choice from an empty sequence does give an IndexError_ Makes sense.  Although as you said, in that case the message is `IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence`, not the reported `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try something like this:

```py
def distant_numbers(base_num, num_list, dist, k):
    if k == 0 or len(num_list) < 2:
        return base_num
    selectables = []
    for num in num_list:
        if math.dist(base_num, num) >= dist:
            selectables.append(num)
    new_base_num = random.choice(selectables)
    return distant_numbers(new_base_num, selectables, dist, k-1)
```

then call function like the following:

```py
for k in range(3):
    print(distant_numbers(base_num, num_list, 0.1, k))
```

The problem with your code is that the function "distant_numbers" continues to call itself without any stopping point, causing an infinite loop. This leads to the "selectables" list being empty and an error when trying to pick a random number from it. To fix this, you can add an exit point to the function where it returns "new_base_num" if the "selectables" list is less than 2 in length. Additionally, you can also limit the number of times the function calls itself by including a parameter to keep track of the recursion count.